# Setting Windows Server 2003 DHCP

Tags: windows, windows-server-2003, dhcp-server

I have a Windows server 2003 with two NIC one is setup to connect to the network with static IP/internet, and the other one is supposed to be used internally as DHCP server. However I am having trouble setting this DHCP. The taskbar icon shows the first NIC with static IP as ok, however the second NIC have limited functionality. I need this NIC to act as DHCP after following some DHCP server how-to.

Any ideas.

Comment: What is it that you're trying to do *exactly*. You talk about setting up DHCP on this server, but you seem to be talking about fiddling with the NICs on the box. You don't configure a DHCP server that way; its a server component that needs to be installed once Windows itself is installed.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to have two NIC's in this configuration.  Disable the 2nd NIC and your DHCP should be running fine on the 1st NIC.  You may be confusing a DHCP Server NIC which needs to have a static IP assigned, vs. a DHCP Client NIC which should be set to automatic/DHCP.  It sounds like you didn't set your second NIC to a static IP, but you don't need two NIC's anyway.